# Facing issue while launching Emulator in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android studio on my system (Windows 10/64 bit).
I am getting an issue when I launch the emulator.

---

```
C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_24
Hax is enabled
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
**adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server**
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

---

I am getting this error:

> Could not automatically detect an ABD binary. Some emulator functionality will not work until a custom path TO abd is added in extended settings page

Please help in resolving this.

Comment: reinstall adb driver

Answer (score 1):

Android emulator eats large part of your RAM. I would suggest you to use GenyMotion which is very fast and wasy to use.Here is the download link for that
[Geny motion](http://filehippo.com/download_genymotion/).

Comment: Thank u for you help... I installed GenyMotion its working fine... :)

Comment: cool.if you think my answer helped you better please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please reduce RAM size of your emulator from Android Virtual Device Manager.